# Generate unique list from nested list that includes dicts in Python

Tags: python, list, uniq

I want to extract unique data from nested list includes dicts, see below.
Is there any efficient way to generate a new uniq list

```
[
  [{'port': 18, 'module': 1, 'policy_group': 'policy_group1'}]
  [{'port': 10, 'module': 1, 'policy_group': 'policy_group2'}]
  [{'port': 10, 'module': 1, 'policy_group': 'policy_group2'}]
]
```

The new list should be

```
[
  [{'port': 18, 'module': 1, 'policy_group': 'policy_group1'}]
  [{'port': 10, 'module': 1, 'policy_group': 'policy_group2'}]
]
```

Comment: What should the output from this input look like?

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the `list` and use `tuple and set` and then convert items in `set` to `dict` again like below:

```
>>> lst = [[{'port': 18, 'module': 1, 'policy_group': 'policy_group1'}],[{'port': 10, 'module': 1, 'policy_group': 'policy_group2'}],[{'port': 10, 'module': 1, 'policy_group': 'policy_group2'}]]

>>> [[dict(item)] for item in set(tuple(l[0].items()) for l in lst)]
[[{'port': 10, 'module': 1, 'policy_group': 'policy_group2'}],
 [{'port': 18, 'module': 1, 'policy_group': 'policy_group1'}]]
```